# show hidden div using jQuery after first checking if it is display none

Tags: jquery

I am making a jQuery function to show a div on click of a button. The button class is  `bip_btn` and the div class is `mi_data_inst`. There is no error, but the div does not show. By default the div with the class `mi_data_inst` has css property `display:none`

HTML structure:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 wpb_column column_container">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element ">
            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <p>
        <button class="wpb_button  wpb_wpb_button wpb_regularsize bip_btn">Take Private Lessons</button>
    </p>
    <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element  mi_data_inst">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
            <p>Demo title</p>
            <p>
            <p>demo content</p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <p></p></div></div>
```

jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".bip_btn", function(e) 
{
    if (jQuery(this).parent("div").find(".mi_data_inst").css('display') == 'none')
    {      
alert("ok--me");     
        jQuery(this).parent("div").find(".mi_data_inst").show();
    }
    else 
    {      
        jQuery(this).parent("div").find(".mi_data_inst").hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @r3mus - not a duplicate, because the problem isn't about detecting if it's hidden, the problem is his selectors aren't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't with detecting if it's visible, it's with your selectors.

Give your HTML structure, this line of jQuery:

```
if ( jQuery(this).parent("div")
```

Is not finding anything.  The button is not inside a div, and it certainly isn't inside a div that then contains the ".mi_data_inst" element.

I personally tend to avoid [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), as it only traverses one level, and if your HTML structure changes at all, this gets broken.  I recommend [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead, because it will travel as far as necessary to find the first relevant selector.

However, given that you don't have a div wrapped around the element, and it seems this is unique, I'm going to suggest changing your selectors completely, as follows:

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".bip_btn", function(e) {
    // Utilize closest
    // Put into a variable, since you're using it more than once
    var parent = jQuery(this).closest(".wpb_column");
    if (parent.find(".mi_data_inst").css('display') == 'none') {      
        alert("ok--me");     
        // Utilize closest
        parent.find(".mi_data_inst").show();
    } else {      
        // Remove the .parent and .find()
        parent.(".mi_data_inst").hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

**Note:**
Your question specifically asks to check if the div in question is set to `display:none`, therefore I've left the structure above as such.  However, if you want to simply check if the div is visible, the other answers here are correct, you could / should check with:

```
if ( ! jQuery(this).closest(".wpb_column").find('.mi_data_inst').is(':visible')) {
    // Show it
} else {
    // Hide it
}
```

Comment: I was using find and next because there are four buttons like this and with four div with the same class . So i wanted something like this that when i click on a button the nearest class named `mi_data_inst` near to button could show

Comment: @user1001176 - First, you need to edit the question to show the `div` that you say is wrapping it.  Second, the div wrapping them may need to have a class, then you probably need to use `.closest('div.myclass')`.

Comment: i tried using `    if (jQuery(this).closest("div.mi_data_inst").css('display') == 'none')` but still it does not seems to be working

Comment: @user1001176 - So, this is the second time I'm suggesting you edit the question to include the div you say is wrapping it.  It's impossible to tell you what's not working without more context.  Additionally, `.closest` is like `.parent`, so you're definitely not going to find "div.mi_data_inst" with .closest.  Maybe you want to try `.siblings()` instead.

Comment: sorry i didnt mentioned but the main div which is wrapping the button and the div which i want to show on click of button is `wpb_wrapper` and its already there in the question

Comment: @user1001176 - So, again - read my answer. Your markup does **NOT** have a div that contains both the button and the div.mi_data_inst. That is the problem.

Comment: i have added a one more div to the question and i got you point that `wpb_wrapper` was being used multiple times . the new main wrapper is `col-sm-6` . Can this be useful ?

Comment: @user1001176 - Check the edit to my answer, utilizing closest, and grabbing the container you added.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to check if an element is visible:

```
if ( $(selector).is(":visible") )
   // the element in $(selector) is visible
```

for your need you can do it as:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).on("click",".bip_btn", function(e) 
{
    if ( jQuery(".mi_data_inst").is(":visible") )
    {      
        jQuery(".mi_data_inst").hide();
    }
    else 
    {      
         jQuery(".mi_data_inst").show();
    }
    return false;
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't solve his problem.  It's a decent technique, but his problem has to do with DOM traversal.

Answer (score 0):

to check if a element is visible you should try like.

```
$(element).is(":visible")
```

in your case

```
$(document).on("click",".bip_btn", function(e) {
    if (!($(".mi_data_inst").is(":visible"))) {      
        alert("hidden");     
        $(".mi_data_inst").show();
    } else {      
        $(".mi_data_inst").hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pYQ83/)